# .load() with data

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I want to load data into a checkout page using `.load()` to load the pages in a modal window. The data that needs to be loaded is a shipping price value, that needs to be usable on the loaded page.

JS

```
function totalCalc() {
var shipping = ($('#shippingform input[name="shipping"]').val());
$('#cartdialog').load("/ash/shop/checkout.php",[$('#shippingform input[name="shipping"]')]);
alert(shipping);
}
```

CHECKOUT.PHP

```
$myTotal = ($subtotal + $_POST['shipping']);
```

I need the value which is shown through the "alert(shipping);" to be a usable value on checkout.php. You'll see I try to `$_POST[]` it in a php variable, but it wont work. I must be sending the data wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the jQuery API, data sent as a query-string format string through `.load()` is treated as GET.  Data sent as a JSON object is treated as POST.  Basically, send it like this:

```
.load("/ash/show/checkout.php", {shipping: shipping});
```

Comment: With this, the checkout.php page will no longer load in the div #cartdialog

Comment: Sorry nevermind, it was just a misspelled word (shop not show). This worked!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
or if you want proper control over it, use the ajax method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Alternatively, you could add the shipping cost to the URL and use $_GET